# How to get the id of a pthread which is given when it is created?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

When creating an pthread, `pthread_create()` is used. First parameter of this function is thread_id.
I tried to access this value `pthread_self()` but this gives something very big and not the numbers I gave while creating.

Is there a way to access this value?

```
for(int i = 0; i < necessaryThreadCount; i++){
        pthread_create(&threadIDs[i], NULL, theFunction, (void*)&requiredStructre[i]);
}
```

my question is, how can i access the value of given threadID inside theFunction?

**Solution:**

I just added another variable to the struct I pass as parameter.

Comment: 1st parameter is pointer to thread id which is declared as below:
pthread_t thread_id;  ID will get assigned when you create thread using pthread_create()

Comment: You don't choose the thread ID.  The system tells you what the thread ID is.

Comment: You mean you want the thread ID of a thread from code running in that thread? Please, also create a [mcve] and describe what happens and what you expect to happen instead.

Answer (score 1):

First parameter is pointer to thread_id which you need to declare first.
ID will get assigned after you create thread using pthread_create(). refer the below:

```
int main()
{
  pthread_t thread; // declare thread
  pthread_create(&thread, NULL, func, NULL);
  printf("the thread id = %d\n", thread);
}
```

Comment: Okay, now how can I access that value, inside the thread when there are multiple threads?

Comment: you can access it using pthread_self() inside thread. Please refer this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pthread-self-in-c

Comment: I know, that function doesn't give me the value I want. What I want is the first parameter of the function pthread_create(). I solved the problem by putting another variable to the structure I pass to the thread.

Answer (score 1):

thread_id is for the new thread that is created. if you execute pthread_self() in the current thread it returns a different value from the newly created thread.

Hope the below example may help you to understand thread id creation:
[NOTE: not a good idea to have global pthread_t declared]
Example:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
  
pthread_t ctid;
  
void* thread_function(void* arg)
{
    printf("Inside the thread\n");
    printf("ctid: %ld, self: %ld", ctid, pthread_self());
    
    // exit the current thread
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
  
void createthread()
{
    pthread_create(&ctid, NULL, &thread_function, NULL);
    printf("This line may be printed"
           " before thread terminates\n");
  
    // Waiting for the created thread to terminate
    pthread_join(ctid, NULL);
  
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
  
// Driver code
int main()
{
    createthread();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You seem to be making some big assumptions about the nature of the OP's problem.

Comment: @john I understand it's not a good coding practice, but the example was only to understand pthread_self() functionality.

Comment: I am not criticizing your code.  I am saying that you seem to assume that the discrepancy the OP describes arises from calling `pthread_self()` in the parent thread rather than the child thread.  Although that could explain the issue, you have no support for that assumption, and other information presented the question and comments inclines me to think that the problem is altogether different.

Comment: @john thanks for sharing your view. it helps.